# Doubt on nearest-neighbour approach to solve TSP

Tags: traveling-salesman

I am a math undergrad and we have algorithms as one of our courses. We came across TSP and algos to solve them. I thought of an algorithm and apparently its already known as the Nearest Neighbour algorithm. Could anyone tell why it might lead to longer tours with instances (short numerical examples maybe) ?

***Thanks in advance!***

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following points on a line, where $0$ is the starting point: $0, 1, -2, 5$. An optimal tour has length $14$, while your algorithm produces a tour of length $1 +3+7+5 = 16$.

Comment: I think that the optimal tour is $14$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, Indeed! Thanks